# I want to create Public and Private Subnet in GCP using terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, private-subnet

**I created a VPC in GCP using Terraform, Now I want to add two subnets Public and private. while creating the VM'S. if I passed the public subnet the VM should get public IP & if I passed private subnet the VM should get an only private internal IP address**

```
## Create VPC
resource "google_compute_network" "vpc" {
     name                    = "${var.name}-vpc"
     auto_create_subnetworks = "false"
    }


    ## Create Subnet
 ##  Create public subnet  

resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "pub-subnet" {
     name          = "${var.name}-public-subnet"
     ip_cidr_range = "${var.pub-subnet-cidr}"
     network       = "${var.name}-vpc"
     depends_on    = ["google_compute_network.vpc"]
     region        = "asia-south1"
    }

## Create private subnet

resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "private-subnet" {
     name          = "${var.name}-private-subnet"
     ip_cidr_range = "${var.private-subnet-cidr}"
     network       = "${var.name}-vpc"
     depends_on    = ["google_compute_network.vpc"]
     region        = "asia-south1"
     private_ip_google_access = "true"
    }
```

#####  Create vm instance

```
  resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {
name = "qa7-web-linux-${count.index + 1}"
count = "${var.count}"
machine_type = "${var.machine_type}"

boot_disk {
     initialize_params {
         image = "${var.web-srv-image}"
         }
     }   
network_interface {
    subnetwork = "${var.subnet-private}"
    access_config {
         }
    }
metadata {
sshKeys = "indra:${file(".//modules//instances//key.pub")}"
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you've posted? Do you get an error when you run it? Does something not happen the way you expect? You should also include your Terraform code that creates your instances if that's the bit that's going wrong.

Comment: I am not getting any error while creating VM instances they are auto-assigned Public IP (even by choosing the private subnet), want to make some changes which will only assign private IP while choosing the private subnet  :)

Comment: Where is your code for the instance creation?

Comment: resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {
name = "qa7-web-linux-${count.index + 1}"
count = "${var.count}"
machine_type = "${var.machine_type}"

boot_disk {
     initialize_params {
         image = "${var.web-srv-image}"
         }
     }   
network_interface {
    subnetwork = "${var.subnet-private}"
    access_config {
         }
    }
metadata {
sshKeys = "indra:${file(".//modules//instances//key.pub")}"
    }
}

Comment: Edit it into your question, not in a comment. And make it so that it's completely reproducible. The [mcve] guide gives a good explanation as to what you should include in a question.

Comment: Added code to create vm instance in private subnet

Comment: Your code show you putting it into the public subnet?

Comment: Edited the code

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I recently ran into the same problem. The problem with your code is that you have a

```
access_config { }
```

block in your network_interface definition. When this is present, an external IP will be assigned to the network interface that is being created. You need to have a different network_interface block without the access_config parameter for VMs in your "private" subnet. Unlike AWS, the subnet isn't really private , b/c you can assign an external IP anytime you want. `private_ip_google_access` probably doesn't mean what you think it means.

Answer (score 0):

just remove 'access config' part from your code and no external ip will be allotted to your vm. Hope this helps.